# Make background images inside skewed container appear un-skewed

Tags: jquery, html, css, skew

I've got a carousel (slick) that's displaying various slides that I've skewed by -10% to create a diagonal effect. However the content inside of it is also skewed. Is there a solution to un-skew just the content and background image but preserve the diagonal effect on the slide container?

Jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/czcjt3no/1/

```
  <div class="section">
  <div class="grid poly--holder">
    <div class="poly-item">
      <div class="poly-item__content" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1000/1000/?random);">sdsfsdsfsdsdfjsdkjfskds</div>
    </div>
    <div class="poly-item">
      <div class="poly-item__content" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1100/1000/?random);">sdsfsdsfsdsdfjsdkjfskds</div>
    </div>
    <div class="poly-item">
      <div class="poly-item__content" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1200/1000/?random);">sdsfsdsfsdsdfjsdkjfskds</div>
    </div>
    <div class="poly-item">
      <div class="poly-item__content" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1300/1000/?random);">sdsfsdsfsdsdfjsdkjfskds</div>
    </div>
    <div class="poly-item">
      <div class="poly-item__content" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1400/1000/?random);">sdsfsdsfsdsdfjsdkjfskds</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.poly--holder {
 overflow: hidden;

 .poly-item {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0;
   transform: skewX(-10deg);
   height: 400px;

   .poly-item__content {
     transform: skewX(10deg);
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50%;
     height: 100%;
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Check this reference https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

Comment: @znaneswar Thanks for that. It's not the most beautiful solution but it's a start - https://jsfiddle.net/czcjt3no/4/

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have put hardcoded values for left and width, here is an updated version with calculated left and widtdh:

```
/* Calculate how much wider the image is than the original image after skewing it */
function calcSkewWidth(degrees, height) {
  return Math.tan(degrees * Math.PI / 180) * height;
}

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('img')].forEach(img => {
    const skewWidth = calcSkewWidth(12, img.offsetHeight);
    img.style.width = `calc(100% + ${skewWidth * 2}px)`;
    img.style.left = `-${skewWidth / 2}px`
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/70rombdv

Answer (score 0):

If you skew the container you have to reverse-skew the content.

Skew is a transformation to the whole DOM node, meaning all it's children will be transformed at once : you cannot stop propagation.

```
.parent{
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
}

.child {
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}
```

[Here is your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0cf5xm7/)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but skewing the child back makes them appear straight where I'm wanting to retain the diagonal slide layout.

Comment: Yes, take a look to my updated fiddle : you have to add a child container inside the `poly-item__content` div. This will prevent your second `skew` rule will override the first one.

Comment: Thanks for helping out - Yeah un-skewing the content is the easy part however the background image is the problem as it's still skewed.

Comment: Oh ok I see... Check the updated fiddle : you have to unskew the image container & play with negative margins and hidden overflow. A bit tricky but should do the job.

Comment: Nice! That's a really simple solution. I was doing something like this which seems a little dirtier - https://jsfiddle.net/czcjt3no/6/ I think I like yours more though